# Is it possible to extract a 'title' instead of a 'class' or 'id' from html to print what appears when you hover over with your mouse?

Tags: python, html, parsing, python-requests, python-requests-html

**Problem Introduction**

Language version: Python 3.8

Operating system: Windows 10

Other relevant Software: Jupyter notebook

Context: I have been learning about web parsing using python and requests_html by isolating CSS selectors for 'class' and 'id'. However, I am not sure how I would isolate 'title' for something that appears when your mouse hovers over an item such as the number next to the top tag on my [account summary page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14340924/cullerwhale).

When I hover over the number 0 next to the python tag its says

> "Asked 7 non-wiki questions with a total score of -1"

When I inspect the number zero in Chrome, I can isolate the html from:

```
<div class="answer-votes" title="Asked 7 non-wiki questions with a total score of -1. " onclick="window.location.href='/search?q=user:14340924+[python]'">0</div>
```

Things I have already tried:

I can get really close to it with this

```
>>> r.html.find('#user-panel-tags')[0].find('.user-tags')[0].find('.answer-votes')[0].text
0
```

```
r.html.find('#user-panel-tags')[0].find('.user-tags')[0].find('.answer-votes')[0].find('.title')[0].text

r.html.find('#user-panel-tags')[0].find('.user-tags')[0].find('.answer-votes title')[0].text
```

Expected outcome:

> Asked 7 non-wiki questions with a total score of -1.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you using `bs4`?

Comment: `title` is an attribute of the element. Use `.attrs()` to get the attributes. Check ==> https://github.com/psf/requests-html

Comment: @Stack, any advice on selecting one (title) of many attributes (class, title, onclick). I couldn't find that answer on the github you sent but it was still immensely helpful, thank you.

Comment: @Mooncrater No, I am not using beautiful soup. I am using requests-html due to educational resources.

Comment: @CullerWhale `.attrs()` returns a dictionary, so you can do `.attrs()['title']` or `.attrs().get('title')`

Comment: @Stack Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously explained in the comments by [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8150371/stack), it is possible to use `.attrs()` to get the attributes of an element. `.attrs()` returns a dictionary which can be indexed using `.attrs()['title']` or `.attrs().get('title')`. Additional resources can be found at https://github.com/psf/requests-html.